# What is hybrid-columnar storage?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cloud, data-warehouse, data-partitioning

Snowflake stores data using a hybrid-columnar storage method. I understand what columnar storage is and its benefits, but what does the **hybrid** mean? Is this simply referring to Snowflake accessing blob storage from different cloud providers?

Comment: Hi - please can you update your question to reference the Snowflake documentation that mentions the hybrid-columnar storage method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake uses PAX [Partition
Attributes Across] aka hybrid columnar storage meaning:

- Horizontal and vertical partitioning
- Automatic column level and partition level compression
- Natural (built-in) data clustering based on ingestion date (order)

This was part of the SIGMOD 2016 presentation, available [here](https://15721.courses.cs.cmu.edu/spring2018/slides/25-snowflake.pdf).

A paper on PAX can be found [here](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/multifacet/papers/vldb01_pax.pdf).